# Issue with workspace setup in RAD using websphere application server 8.5

Tags: ibm-rad, ibm-was

I am really having a hard time is setting up my workspace. I ws trying to configure and run m WAS8.5 by using a .car file but it is giving me a tuff time. I tried configuring the server manually but still I could not start the server. WHile starting server I am getting the below error in the console and after that server got stopped.

Server log:

```
************ Start Display Current Environment ************
Host Operating System is Windows 7, version 6.1
Java version = 1.6.0, Java Compiler = j9jit26, Java VM name = IBM J9 VM
was.install.root = C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer
user.install.root = C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01
Java Home = C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java\jre
ws.ext.dirs = C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/java/lib;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01/classes;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/classes;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/lib;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/installedChannels;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/lib/ext;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/web/help;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/deploytool/itp/plugins/com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy/runtime
Classpath = C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01/properties;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/properties;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/lib/startup.jar;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/lib/bootstrap.jar;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/lib/jsf-nls.jar;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/lib/lmproxy.jar;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/lib/urlprotocols.jar;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/deploytool/itp/batchboot.jar;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/deploytool/itp/batch2.jar;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/java/lib/tools.jar
Java Library path = C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/lib/native/win/x86_32/;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java\jre\bin\default;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java\jre\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\lib\native\win\x86_64;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\bin;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java\bin;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Blue Coat\ProxyClient\;.;
Orb Version = IBM Java ORB build orb626-20120304.00
************* End Display Current Environment *************
[4/18/14 10:59:22:519 EDT] 00000001 ManagerAdmin  I   TRAS0017I: The startup trace state is *=info.
[4/18/14 10:59:22:520 EDT] 00000001 ManagerAdmin  I   TRAS0111I: The message IDs that are in use are deprecated
[4/18/14 10:59:22:642 EDT] 00000001 ModelMgr      I   WSVR0800I: Initializing core configuration models
[4/18/14 10:59:22:714 EDT] 00000001 WsServerImpl  E   WSVR0009E: Error occurred during startup
java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.ibm.ws.config.ModelMgr.initializeModels(ModelMgr.java:342)
    at com.ibm.ws.config.ModelMgr.initialize(ModelMgr.java:152)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.start(WsServerImpl.java:264)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.main(WsServerImpl.java:730)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer.main(WsServer.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.launchMain(WSLauncher.java:234)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:95)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.run(WSLauncher.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:981)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:376)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.ibm.ws.config.ModelMgr.performInitialization(ModelMgr.java:607)
    at com.ibm.ws.config.ModelMgr.processInitializer(ModelMgr.java:564)
    at com.ibm.ws.config.ModelMgr.loadModelsViaEclipse(ModelMgr.java:499)
    at com.ibm.ws.config.ModelMgr.initializeModels(ModelMgr.java:338)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.ibm.ws.config.ModelMgr.performInitialization(ModelMgr.java:634)
    at com.ibm.ws.config.ModelMgr.performInitialization(ModelMgr.java:604)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at com.ibm.ws.config.ModelMgr.performInitialization(ModelMgr.java:631)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.jem.internal.java.init.JavaInit.preRegisterPackages(JavaInit.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jem.internal.java.init.JavaInit.init(JavaInit.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.J2EEInit.init(J2EEInit.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.helpers.ArchiveInit.invokePrereqInits(ArchiveInit.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.helpers.ArchiveInit.init(ArchiveInit.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.helpers.ArchiveInit.init(ArchiveInit.java:45)
    at com.ibm.websphere.models.config.init.ReadOnlyConfigInit.initializeCommonArchive(ReadOnlyConfigInit.java:110)
    at com.ibm.websphere.models.config.init.ReadOnlyConfigInit.init(ReadOnlyConfigInit.java:90)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jem.java.internal.impl.JavaRefPackageImpl.initializePackageContents(JavaRefPackageImpl.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.jem.java.internal.impl.JavaRefPackageImpl.initGen(JavaRefPackageImpl.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.jem.java.internal.impl.JavaRefPackageImpl.init(JavaRefPackageImpl.java:211)
    at org.eclipse.jem.java.JavaRefPackage.<clinit>(JavaRefPackage.java:1564)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:228)
    ... 47 more
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due a bug in websphere in windows 7 64 bits. Try to copy all dll's from `C:\IBM\WebSphere8\AppServer\lib\native\win\x86_32` into `C:\IBM\WebSphere8\AppServer\lib\native\win\x86_64` folder(don't forget to save the old files in some place first).

It is not an elegant solution but it works.